# How do I drop specific NaN values while keeping others based on a pattern of NaNs in the dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe like this:

[image: initial dataframe]

The pattern it follows is that if the first n rows of Column A are populated, then the next n rows will be "populated" (populated cells could have NaN values as well, but I call them "populated" because I'd like to keep those) for Column B i.e. rows 'n+1' to '2n'. And Column C will have the next n rows i.e. '2n+1' to '3n' "populated", and so on for the rest of the columns.
So in the above example, Column A has the first 3 cells populated, Column B has the next 3 cells (cells 4 to 6) populated, and Column C has the next 3 cells after that (cells 7 to 9) populated.

Important: When certain cells for a column are populated, the corresponding cells in the same rows will be empty for ALL other columns.

After this pattern continues for all columns, it loops back and Column A is populated again, in this case it's 4 cells that are populated this time. So the next 4 cells of Column B are what I want to keep and the next next 4 cells of column C are what I want to keep.
Ending up with a dataframe like this:

[image: final desired dataframe]

Initially, I tried dropping all NaN cells but realized that NaN cells that I wanted to keep got dropped too. Then I thought of dropping just the NaN cells that are not in between 2 non-NaN cells but the NaN cells I want to keep won't necessarily be between two non-NaN cells like in the example.

I guess the only way I can think of is counting the non-NaN values in column A (say it's x number of rows that are non-NaN) and then dropping the first x rows from Column B, first 2x rows from Column C, first 3x rows from Column D and so on.
And also dropping the cells after the cells I want to keep from each column which would depend on the number of columns remaining i.e. if there are y number of columns after column A then dropping x*y cells after the first x cells in column A; dropping x*(y-1) cells (after the cells I want to keep) from Column B and so on. But not sure how to do this or even repeat this when the pattern loops and Column A is populated again.

Code for input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'colA': ['A','B','C','','','','','','','W','X','Y','Z','','','','','','','','',], 
 'colB': ['','','',1,'',2,'','','','','','','',3,'','',4,'','','',''],
'colC': ['','','','','','','a','b','c','','','','','','','','','d','e','f','']})
```

Comment: can you provide code or text of input?

Comment: it's an easy problem, so I'll solve the problem if you just create the code for the input. it is difficult for me to create input code one by one (looking your input image).

Comment: How do I create code for the input? I have the csv file for this example, but can't see a way to upload it here

Comment: you can make your example to code not file or image. use `pd.DataFrame` func

Comment: Ok @PandaKim, added the input code. Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

df of post should be modified as below

```
df = df.replace({'':None})
```

**Code**

at first find number of group. If there is no intermediate NaN in colA, you can find it in the following way

```
grouper = df['colA'].notna().ne(df['colA'].notna().shift()).cumsum()
lst = df['colA'].notna()[lambda x: x.eq(1)].groupby(grouper).sum().tolist()
```

`lst`

```
[3, 4]
```

make dataframe for pivot

```
df1 = df.ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)['colA'].to_frame('value')
df1['cols'] = [j for i in lst for j in df.columns for k in range(i)]
df1['index'] = df1.groupby('cols').cumcount()
```

`df1`

```
value   cols    index
0   A   colA    0
1   B   colA    1
2   C   colA    2
3   1   colB    0
4   NaN colB    1
5   2   colB    2
6   a   colC    0
7   b   colC    1
8   c   colC    2
9   W   colA    3
10  X   colA    4
11  Y   colA    5
12  Z   colA    6
13  3   colB    3
14  NaN colB    4
15  NaN colB    5
16  4   colB    6
17  d   colC    3
18  e   colC    4
19  f   colC    5
20  NaN colC    6
```

pivot

```
df1.pivot(index='index', columns='cols', values='value')
```

output :

```
cols    colA    colB    colC
index           
0       A       1       a
1       B       NaN     b
2       C       2       c
3       W       3       d
4       X       NaN     e
5       Y       NaN     f
6       Z       4       NaN
```

Comment: This works for a small data frame size, however it keeps crashing when I try for my actual large data set. Is there a more performant way to do this, or is my only option to split up my data into smaller parts and do this for each one?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (*starting from your input table/screenshot*) :

```
grp = (df["Column 1"].shift(1).isnull() & df["Column 1"].notnull()).cumsum()
​
out = pd.concat([df.groupby(grp)[col].apply(lambda g:
                    g.loc[g.first_valid_index():g.last_valid_index()])
            .reset_index(drop=True) for col in df.columns], axis=1)
```

​Output :

```
print(out)

  Column 1  Column 2 Column 3
0        A      1.00        a
1        B       NaN        b
2        C      2.00        c
3        W      3.00        d
4        X       NaN        e
5        Y       NaN        f
6        Z      4.00      NaN
```

Comment: **NB**: This approach assumes you want to remove *leading & trailing* `NaN` values in each group.

Comment: It seems to be failing when a group starts with a NaN e.g. if the last 4 rows for Column 3 were NaN,d,e,Nan then the output returns d,e,NaN,NaN instead

Answer (score 0):

One option, using a [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#flexible-apply) with a custom function:

```
# this function move the value up in a Series
# keeping the starting values of the index
def cust_reshape(df):
    n = df.iloc[:,0].ne('').sum()
    return pd.DataFrame({c: df[c].iloc[i*n:(i+1)*n].to_numpy()
                         for i, c in enumerate(df)},
                        index=df.index[:n]
                       )

m = df['colA'].ne('')

(df.groupby((m & ~m.shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum(),
            group_keys=False)
   .apply(cust_reshape)
)
```

*NB. to consider NaN and not empty strings, replace `.ne('')` with `.notna()`*

Output:

```
   colA colB colC
0     A    1    a
1     B         b
2     C    2    c
9     W    3    d
10    X         e
11    Y         f
12    Z    4
```

Comment: This is failing when the group of a column starts with a NaN. e.g. if I change colC such that the last 4 rows are "NaN,d,e,NaN" then the output becomes "d,e,NaN,NaN":
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'colA': ['A','B','C','','','','','','','W','X','Y','Z','','','','','','','','',], 
     'colB': ['','','',1,'',2,'','','','','','','','3','','','4','','','',''],
    'colC': ['','','','','','','a','b','c','','','','','','','','','','d','e','']})
df = df.replace({'':np.NaN})

Comment: @AOP if a group can start with a NaN, how do you make the difference with the previous column ending on a NaN? Or is the size determined by the number of values in ColA?

Comment: That's right, the size is determined by the number of values in ColA. Note that ColA will never have the in-between in-group NaN values. If ColA has 4 continuous non-NaN values that means the group size is 4 for each column. You can think of other columns as attributes of ColA meaning in the latest e.g. W has attributes 3 and NaN, X has NaN and d, Y has NaN and e, Z has 4 and NaN

Comment: Ok then there should be more straightforward and efficient methods, busy now but I'll update my answer later.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test on a larger dataset and let you know! What do I replace .ne('').sum with if working with NaNs?

Comment: I already wrote it in my answer as comment: ***NB. to consider NaN and not empty strings, replace `.ne('')` with `.notna()`*** (there are 2 occurrences in the code)